# Collection of Types rather than Instances

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of viewmodels that currently instantiates all the viewmodels at the start:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<ViewModelWithTemplate> StepViewModels
{
    get
    {
        if (_stepViewModels == null)
            _stepViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelWithTemplate>
        {
            new AddRemoveCellsViewModel(TemplateRows),
            new ActivateDeactivateCellsViewModel(TemplateRows),
            new RotateCellsViewModel(TemplateRows),
            new SetAcquisitionOrderViewModel(TemplateRows),
            new NameTemplateViewModel(TemplateRows)
        };
        return _stepViewModels;
    }
}

public ViewModelWithTemplate CurrentStepViewModel => StepViewModels[StepIndex];
```

The problem is that the VMs are created all at once, but I want them to be only created when needed, mainly so that they have the most recent edition of `TemplateRows`.

How can I do this? My first thought is to have the collection be a list of *types* so that I can instantiate each viewmodel when I arrive at it, like this:

```cs
public ViewModelWithTemplate CurrentStepViewModel => new StepViewModels[StepIndex](TemplateRows);
```

But a little Googling around makes me think the answer is more toward inversion of control, and/or a VM factory. I'm having trouble finding actual helpful information that's not tied to some framework. (Prism, etc)

Comment: You can use reflection and `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Do you mean instead of `new WhateverViewModel`? That's good, but I still need a collection of **types**, not instances of a type.

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ -- is this possible? Yes, of course. It's software. If you can state a problem in a clear, unambiguous way, and the problem has strictly to do with the way the software itself works, it's _always_ "possible". Asking whether it is, is not useful and too broad. **What have you tried? What _specifically_ do you need help with?**

Comment: @JonathanTuzman If you want to use generic types, than you should use parameterless constructor and set `TemplateRows` via property. Also you should manage the proper constraints

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think "is this possible" pretty well implies "how do I do this?".

Comment: That said, I frankly question the usefulness of what you're asking to do. View models should be, by their very design, lightweight objects, for which there should be no problem instantiating any number of them. You can implement some type of factory delegate, for example, but that doesn't seem like it actually solves any real problem, unnecessarily complicates the code, and doesn't even necessarily improve efficiency.

Comment: _"I think "is this possible" pretty well implies "how do I do this?""_ -- not in a useful way, it doesn't. Even if we take it as given that we should reinterpret your _stated_ question as one that asks something quite different (which is already a stretch), things which are possible often have many different ways of accomplishing, which is the very definition of a question that is **too broad**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1) delegates (assuming `StepIndex` is of type `int` and `TemplateRows` is of type `TemplateRowsType`):

```
// this can be moved to static prop:
var stepViewModelsCtorDict = new Dictionary<int, Func<TemplateRowsType, ViewModelWithTemplate>>
{
   {0, trows => new AddRemoveCellsViewModel(trows) },    
   {1, trows => new ActivateDeactivateCellsViewModel(trows) },
....
};

var result = stepViewModelsCtorDict[StepIndex](TemplateRows);
```

Comment: Works great! Except it doesn't need to be a dictionary: since the `int`s are equal to the index, it can just be a list.

Comment: @JonathanTuzman was glad to help! I tend to use dictionaries in such cases cause they are more universal (StepIndex could have been an enum, for example =)